# get list of items, which were passed from python file (Django) to html, from html to Javascript, which is on the same page

Tags: javascript, python, django

my python code:

```
def index(request):
    body=list(Body.objects.all())
    loads=list(Load.objects.all().order_by('length'))
    badLoads=[]
    goodLoads=[]
    for load in loads:
        if load.length>body[0].length or load.width>body[0].width or load.mass>body[0].mass:
            badLoads.append(load)
        else:
            goodLoads.append(load)

    goodLoadsLength=len(goodLoads)
    context={
        'body':body[0],
        'loads':loads,
        'badLoads':badLoads,
        'goodLoads':goodLoads,
        'goodLoadsLength':goodLoadsLength,
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        {% if body %}
            <p>body length: {{ body.length }}, body width: {{ body.width }}, body height: {{ body.height }}, body max mass, which can be taken: {{ body.mass }}</p>
        {% else %}
            <p>No parameters found</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% if loads %}
            <ul>
            {% for load in loads %}
                <li>load id: {{ load.id }}, load length:{{ load.length }}, load width: {{load.width}}, load height: {{load.height}}, load mass: {{load.mass}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No loads are available.</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% if goodLoads %}
            <ul>
            {% for goodLoad in goodLoads %}
                <li>load id: {{ goodLoad.id }}, load length:{{ goodLoad.length }}, load width: {{goodLoad.width}}, load height: {{goodLoad.height}}, load mass: {{goodLoad.mass}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No loads are available.</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% if loads %}
        <ul>
        {% for badLoad in badLoads %}
            <li>load id: {{ badLoad.id }}, load length:{{ badLoad.length }}, load width: {{badLoad.width}}, load height: {{badLoad.height}}, load mass: {{badLoad.mass}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No loads are available.</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <script>
        const loadsLength="{{goodLoadsLength}}";
        const goodLoads="{{goodLoads}}"
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to do a simple table with the help of javascript on the same page. I know I can do a table through html, but  I would like to do it through Javascript, on the same page. But somehow I can see in script simple variables, like this one:

```
const loadsLength="{{goodLoadsLength}}";
```

But I cannot do list of items. The number of items can be different. So it should be going through for or forEach loop, but script does not give me any chance to get the members of a list in case of python(or array in case of javascript) into javascript block. If I try:

```
const goodLoads="{{goodLoads}}";
 console.log(goodLoads);
```

It gives me:

```
[&lt;Load: Load object (1)&gt;]
```

Which seems like it sees the object in array. But when I try:

```
 console.log(goodLoads[0].length);
```

or

```
foodLoads.forEach(item=>{
    console.log(item.length)
})
```

It gives me: the object is undefined. I tried couple of more approaches like with for loop with for object in objects, or normal for loops with the step++ way. But the object is undefined.

I guess I don't understand how to get the list/array from html to script block. It should be seen as normal array of items. But I cannot get them. Can somebody pinpoint me to the answer? Thank you.

Comment: in script block, it should be simple: const arrayName="{{contextArrayFromDjango}}", but it does not give me array to array equivalent. I understand that I am on the right path since simple variables are seeing in the script block, but how to get an array?

Comment: Should I write JSON in python and read it in Javascript?

Comment: One option is to JSON-dumps the data into a text field in your HTML template, the JSON-loads the data on the javascript side. It's not super elegant but it will work. The javascript can DOM-remove the field after it loads the data.

Comment: But it would be strange and counter productive since the context and so arrays already in DOM. And just simply can be read in Javascript.

Comment: The strange thing, that I still can see simple variable in Javascript block. So I truly think I do not understand how to extract array from DOM while in Javascript block. I will try to look up for JSON dumps. Thank you. And it also on command console tells me there is object/s under this array name. Just cannot get it. I saw somewhere like: const name=["{{object1}},{{object2}}"], but I won't know how many members of iarray I will have on output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Django built-in `json_script` (see documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)) template tag to safely output a python object as JSON wrapped in a script tag. Then in your main JS script, you can parse the JSON object and do all standard operations with it.

In your template:

```
{{ goodLoads|json_script:"goodLoads"}}
```

In your main JS file:

```
 let goodLoads = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('goodLoads').textContent);
```

Another issue is that you're passing QuerySet objects into the context variable goodLoads. It won't be very useful to have those objects in your JS file, because you cannot access the object field values. For that turn the QuerySet object into a dict before passing it to the context.

For example using queryset.values(),

```
def index(request):
    body=list(Body.objects.all())
    loads=list(Load.objects.all().order_by('length'))
    badLoads=[]
    goodLoads=[]
    for load in loads:
        if load.length>body[0].length or load.width>body[0].width or load.mass>body[0].mass:
            badLoads.append(load.values()) #converting to dict here
        else:
            goodLoads.append(load.values()) #converting to dict here

    goodLoadsLength=len(goodLoads)
    context={
        'body':body[0],
        'loads':loads,
        'badLoads':badLoads,
        'goodLoads':goodLoads,
        'goodLoadsLength':goodLoadsLength,
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```